# Angularjs $http then function

Tags: angularjs, http, promise

I've created a JS Object with a method that calls a $http to retrieve a value, but when the $http is done I want to assign this value to a property, I can't seem to be able to get this value:

the property this.user always ends up with the promise itself, but I want to assign the value returned from the XHR Request or undefined on failure, I think this is a context problem, I just don't know how to fix it

```
var Ticket = function(numint, company_id, user_id, title, description, priority, status, assignation, created_at) {
            this.numint         = numint;
            this.company_id     = company_id;
            this.user_id        = user_id;
            this.title          = title;
            this.description    = description;
            this.priority       = priority;
            this.status         = status;
            this.assignation    = assignation;
            this.created_at     = created_at;

            this.user           = undefined;

            this.getUser = function() {

                if(this.user_id === undefined)
                    return false;

                var http = 
                    $http({
                        method  : 'GET',
                        url     : '/users/' + this.user_id,
                        timeout : 100000,
                        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                    });

                this.user = http
                    .then(
                        function(data) {
                            return data;
                        }
                        , 
                        function() {
                            return undefined;
                        });

                return http;

            }
        };
```

Comment: `$http` is an async operation - you can't `return` the value from the success handler and assign it `this.user` - you have to assign it inside the handler: `self.user = data;` and assign `var self = this;` beforehand

Comment: yes I though so, But how do I reference the this.user inside the handler??? if I type this.user... the context is wrong, the this is pointing to the handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var http` is a promise object because the return value of Angular's `$http` service is a promise ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)). Use `.then()` to get the return value once the AJAX request has returned and the promise has resolved.

```
var self = this;

http.then(function (data) {
  self.user = data;
});
```

Comment: I've tried this, it doesn't work, the this is pointing to the function handler, not to my object

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich, I edited Morgan's question to fix the `this` reference

Comment: slight difference. instead of then I used .success so data is the actual data. otherwise I had to do data.data

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich it's fine to use .success() to just return the data instead of .then() to return the whole response object. Just remember that .success() and .error() are convenience functions unique to Angular's $http and $resource services. So if you ever change your code so that the promise is not returned from $http (such as loading data from a cache) then .success() and .error() will no longer be there. A more in-depth explanation of the difference between .success(), .error() and .then() can be found [here](http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var Ticket = function(numint, company_id, user_id, title, description, priority, status, assignation, created_at) {
        var self = this; // new code
        self.numint         = numint; //use self inseat
        self.company_id     = company_id;

        this.getUser = function() {

            if(self.user_id === undefined) // you had one preblem here, because "this" here is direrent to the this.user_id you neded, so use self
                return false;

            var http = 
                $http({
                    method  : 'GET',
                    url     : '/users/' + this.user_id,
                    timeout : 100000,
                    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                }).then(function (data){
                      self.user = data
                   ;},
                 function () {
                  self.user= undefined;
                   });


        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

assign this to a different value OR! or us .bind.

```
$http({
  method  : 'GET',
  url     : '/users/' + this.user_id,
  timeout : 100000,
  headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).then(function (data){
  this.user = data;
}.bind(this));
```